# What does getNameCount() actually count?

Tags: java, path, filenames

My question has two parts - First, exactly what the title is - What is the Path.getNameCount() method actually counting? I read the little popup information that comes with it when you select a method in Eclipse, and I thought that this was an appropriate usage. This method I've created utilizing it is returning 5 as the int when it's run. Secondly, what I'm *trying* to do is return how many files are in the target directory so that I can run the other method I have to retrieve file names an appropriate number of times. If the getNameCount() method is not appropriate for this function, might you have any suggestions on how to accomplish the same ends?

```
//Global Variable for location of directory
Path dir = FileSystems.get("C:\\Users\\Heather\\Desktop\\Testing\\Testing2");
//Method for collecting the count of the files in the target directory.
public int Count()
{
    int files=0;
    files = dir.getNameCount();
    return files;
}
}
```

Comment: `FileSystems.getDefault().getPath` should be replaced with `Paths.get`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As [documented](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Path.html#getNameCount--), `getNameCount()` returns:

> the number of elements in the path, or 0 if this path only represents a root component

So in your case, the elements are `"Users"`, `"Heather"`, `"Desktop"`, `"Testing"` and `"Testing2"` - *not* the names of the file within the directory.

To list the files in a directory, you can use [`Files.list(Path)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#list-java.nio.file.Path-) (in Java 8+) or [`Files.newDirectoryStream(Path)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#newDirectoryStream-java.nio.file.Path-) (in Java 7+). Or you can convert to a `File` and use the "old school" [`File.listFiles()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/File.html#listFiles--) method etc.

Comment: `Files.list` present only since Java 8, please, mention it.

Comment: @DmitryGinzburg: Done, with various alternatives.

Answer (score 5):

`getNameCount()` returns number of elements in the path (subdirectories). For example, in Windows for "C:" that would be 0, and for "C:\a\b\c" - 3, in Unix-like systems, root ("/") would be at 0-level (`getNameCount() == 0`) and "/home/user/abacaba" will be at the 3rd level, see [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Path.html#getNameCount%28%29)

To list directory you should use `DirectoryStream`: [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/DirectoryStream.html) - perfect example is given here.

Answer (score 1):

It returns the number of elements in the path.

Check [Oracle Docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Path.html#getNameCount--)

Example:-

```
Path path = Paths.get("C:", "tutorial/Java/JavaFX", "Topic.txt");

System.out.println(path.getNameCount());
```

Returns:

```
4
```

Comment: Maybe because your original answer mentioned the "number of elements in the subfolder" which was a bit confusing (number of files in the folder?).

Comment: @assylias:- But now I have updated that and I was updating my answer while it got downvoted. I was tryng to add an example :(

Comment: FYI whoever downvoted you can't remove its downvote because you made all the changes within 5 minutes. You should make a small edit again to unlock your post.

Comment: @assylias:- Done that! :)