# How to check if a string representing a path is composed by exactly 3 sub directories in Java?

Tags: java, string, algorithm, split

into a Java application I have the following situation and I want ask you an advice about how to handle it in a smart way.

I have this collection (a list of String representing the paths of some directories):

```
List<String> path = new ArrayList<String>();
```

After an initialization phase this **path** list contains something like the following String objects:

```
/KMS
/KMS/GEOTHERMAL
/KMS/HYDROELECTRIC
/KMS/SOLAR
/KMS/WIND
/KMS/WIND/BRAZIL
/KMS/WIND/CAMEX
/KMS/WIND/ITALY_EUROPE
/KMS/GEOTHERMAL/BRAZIL
........................
........................
........................
```

So, a single row represent a single String object into the **path** list.

I need to do the following operation:

- If a string represents a path having less than three subfolder then discard it (so for example, strings as **/KMS** or **/KMS/HYDROELECTRIC** have to be discard.
- If a string represents a path having 3 subfolder print the third subfolder (so for example if the string is something like **/KMS/WIND/BRAZIL** print **BRAZIL**).

Obviously I know that I have to iterate on my **path** list to check each String object but how can I do the previous check in a smart way?

Tnx

Comment: Possibly naive solution: split on `/` and you must have three parts left.

Comment: `if (path.get(i).split("/").length == 3) { // do your stuff }`

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24264942/what-does-getnamecount-actually-count

Comment: @Jongware @SashaSalauyou Since OP wrote *subfolder* your suggestions would only work if the string starts with a `'/'` so *root* is the "parent folder". If this is not the case, you need *4* slashes to have *3* subfolder.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use [Path::getNameCount](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Path.html#getNameCount--) (Java 7+):

```
Paths.get(path).getNameCount() == 3
```

as a condition to filter your list.

If you just want to remove invalid paths from your list, you could simply write (Java 8+):

```
path.removeIf(s -> Paths.get(s).getNameCount() != 3);
```

With Java 6 or earlier, you probably need to split the string:

```
List<String> validPaths = ...;
for (String p : path) {
  //CAREFUL: == 4 for a 3-deep path, because the root "" counts for 1
  if (p.split("/").lentgh == 4) valiPaths.add(p);
}
```

Comment: For the sake of clarity, this code assumes the use of Java 8+. Given that the OP uses `new ArrayList<String>();` I'm not sure he's using such a version.

Comment: @assylias mmm I am using Java 1.6 on this project (and I can't change it). I tryied your solution but it can't resolve the get method on the Paths class

Comment: @AndreaNobili Then you'll have to do it manually and split the string I'm afraid... Note that doing it manually may create issues on some OSes.

Comment: Ok, if you add the manually solution (splitting) I can formally accept your answer. Let also the posted solution that could be very usefull for who use Java 7\8 :-)

Comment: @AndreaNobili here you go.

Comment: Ok, tnx. Perfect explaination :-)